# Can we use multiple Hibernate createSQLQuery in same method without closing or flushing session or transaction

Tags: performance, hibernate, session

I have a doubt on `createSQLQuery()` of Hibernate session. In my application while using save or load method everywhere we are using `beginTransaction()` and then `commitTransaction()` but when using `createSQLQuery()` by session no where using `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()`. Even with same hibernate session is being used with multiple `createSQLQuery()` in the same method. Is it the right way to use `createSQLQuery()`, i.e. its not needed `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()` for insert/update and there is no need to flush Hibernate session everytime we are using with `createSQLQuery()`? By doing so will it not impact performance of the application?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is read-only operations, (and you are sure that there is not going to be any concurrent operations on your tables) you can perform multiple read-only SQL queries from the same Hibernate Session. However, if there is the possibility that there could be concurrent operations on your tables, or you are inserting/updating before reading, then you need to be at least flushing and clearing the session in between operations to prevent dirty reads.

While its not recommended, you only need to call `beginTransaction()` when you are inserting/updating data. That way if the insert/update fails, Hibernate will automatically rollback the changes by wrapping the operation in the `TransactionManager` bean, which also handles your exceptions. While it is not considered good practice, you don't strictly need to call `beginTransaction()` when performing read-only operations as you aren't affecting the database state. However that doesn't mean that an exception isn't going to be thrown. If an exception is thrown and you don't have an active transaction, then Hibernate is not able to perform any exception handling.

It's generally best practice to encapsulate each query within its own DAO method that manages the Hibernate session. While this does mean that you can only perform one query at a time (per method call) its safer than performing many queries within the same session. As a rule of thumb, unless your performance is critical, data integrity trumps performance every time.

Comment: Its really helpful for me. My question is when we have multiple hibernate session with createSQLQuery(Insert/Update) in same method,so I need to flush every time or it just needed one flush at the end.Also if I use beginTransaction and commitTransaction for every createSQLQuery .executeUpdate() then can I use the same hibernate session for next createSQLQuery. Reason why I am asking it as I can see LockAcquisitionException in my log,what I feel that it could be due to insert and update happening in createSQLQuery not using commitTransaction and session is not being flushed anywhere.

Comment: Yes, if you are getting LockAcquisionException then you need to be flushing the session in between inserts